# Getting 'ORA00904: invalid identifier' on dynamic tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-00904

I have a script that works with dynamic tables. When executing the below code segment, it gives me error `ORA00904: invalid identifier`.

```
IF Database_SYS.Column_Exist (service_tab_, ''KEY_VALUE'') THEN                           
   UPDATE '|| service_tab_ || '
   SET key_ref    = new_key_ref_,                                  
   key_value  = ''Test'',                                  
   rowversion = SYSDATE
   WHERE ROWID    = rec_.ROWID;                                                      
ELSE                                              
   UPDATE '|| service_tab_ || '
   SET key_ref    = new_key_ref_,                               
   rowversion = SYSDATE
   WHERE ROWID    = rec_.ROWID;                           
END IF;
```

Comment: Which database are you using and please share your table structure too

Comment: As these oracle database  tables are dynamic, KEY_VALUE column can be exists or not depending on the table structure. There is no unique structure for the tables.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Some informations are needed to give you a working solution. What is the signature of the `Database_SYS.Column_Exist` function? (this is needed to understand how to pass it the column name). Is `new_key_ref_` a variable or column of both involved tables? And what is its type? Assuming `_rec` is a variable, what is the type of `rec_.ROWID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be better this one:

```
BEGIN
    IF Database_SYS.Column_Exist (service_tab_, '''' || KEY_VALUE || '''') THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
            'UPDATE ' || service_tab_ || '
                SET key_ref    = new_key_ref_,
                    key_value  = :val,
                    rowversion = SYSDATE
              WHERE ROWID    = :rid'
        USING 'TEST', rec_.ROWID;
    ELSE
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
            'UPDATE ' || service_tab_ || '
                SET key_ref    = new_key_ref_,
                    rowversion = SYSDATE
              WHERE ROWID    = :rid'
        USING rec_.ROWID;
    END IF;
END;
```

I don't think you need `'''' || KEY_VALUE || ''''`, using just `Database_SYS.Column_Exist(service_tab_, KEY_VALUE)` should be fine if you have properly coded the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'update' ||  service_tab_ || 'SET key_ref    = ' ||new_key_ref_|| ' rowversion = SYSDATE   WHERE ROWID    = '|| rec_.ROWID;
```

LEt me know if you get further errors, we can resolve them together in comments.

Comment: key_value cannot be eliminated. Key_value is the main column that should be updated, That's the purpose of putting this IF / ELSE block.

Comment: I have shown the sample of the query mentioned in your else clause..you can similarly create the query for the if portion

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
    IF Database_SYS.Column_Exist (service_tab_, '''' || KEY_VALUE || '''') -- 4x': StartString + Quote + ' + EndString  doublepipe to concat Strings
    THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE -- If you want to Build dynamic SQL you have to throw it into "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'myQuery'"
            'UPDATE ' || service_tab_ || '
                SET key_ref    = new_key_ref_,
                    key_value  = ''TEST'',
                    rowversion = SYSDATE
              WHERE ROWID    = rec_.ROWID';
    ELSE
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
            'UPDATE ' || service_tab_ || '
                SET key_ref    = new_key_ref_,
                    rowversion = SYSDATE
              WHERE ROWID    = rec_.ROWID';
    END IF;
END;
```

Next time you should Build up your script step-by-step. A single Error can be handled better than having a bunch of invalid code..

Answer (score 0):

If the only difference is in updating a column it would be more correct to apply the condition only to a part of the query

```
DECLARE
    V_QUERY VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
    --
    V_QUERY := 'UPDATE '||service_tab_||
               '   SET key_ref    = new_key_ref_,              
                     rowversion = SYSDATE';
  --
    IF Database_SYS.Column_Exist (service_tab_, 'KEY_VALUE') THEN   
    V_QUERY := V_QUERY||', key_value  = ''Test''';
  END IF;
  --
  V_QUERY := V_QUERY||' WHERE ROWID    = rec_.ROWID';
  --
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_QUERY;
  --
END;
```